# Проблемы с конвертацией byte array в String и обратно Java

Tags: java

Почему после конвертации в String и обратно меняется массив byte. при чем такое происходит не с каждым массивом байт, вот пример кода который это демонстрирует.

```
byte[] result = new byte[]
    {0, 0, 0, 97, 63, -44, 55, -19, 51, 16, -39, -106, 0, 0, 0,
    18, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 63, -32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 63, -84,
    113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113,
    -57, 28, 115, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 100, 63,
    -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 117, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28,
    113, -57, 28, 108, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109,
    63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 111, 63, -68, 113, -57, 
    28, 113, -57, 28, 0};
byte[] result2 = new byte[]
    {0, 0, 0, 115, 63, -29, -103, 75, 42, 114, -97, 67, 0, 0, 0,
    18, 0, 0, 0, 11, -1, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0,
    63, -36, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 32, 63, -84, 113, -57,
    28, 113, -57, 28, 112, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28,
    -2, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113,
    -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 101, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57,
    28, 105, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 76, 63, -84,
    113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113,
    -57, 28, 111, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0};

try {
    Object data = new String(result, "UTF-16BE");
    byte[] workingData = ((String) data).getBytes("UTF-16BE");
    Object data2 = new String(result2, "UTF-16BE");
    byte[] workingData2 = ((String) data2).getBytes("UTF-16BE");
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(result, workingData));
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(result2, workingData2));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Есть причины именно с такой кодировкой работать? Может удобнее Base64 будет https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: Да, это требование по формату данных.

Comment: Переписал комментарий, чтобы не засорять его ненужной информацией, добавил код для теста.

Comment: В левом нижнем окошке IDE по экспереминтируйте с кодировками. Авось получится. UTF-8 всему виной, мой ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод getBytes отработал очень криво в первом случае. По моему скромному мнению, плохо он отработал, потому что у вас включена (как и у меня) UTF-8. И вы конвертируете в какие-то иероглифы. Для корректной конвертации нужно включить какую-то другую кодировку. Вот гляньте:

```
 System.out.println("data = " + data);
 System.out.println("data2 = " + data2);
```

OUTPUT:

```
data =  a㿔㟭㌐�   ?   㾬燇ᱱ윜爿걱윜燇ᱳ㾬燇ᱱ윜搿걱윜燇ᱵ㾬燇ᱱ윜氿걱윜燇ᱭ㾬燇ᱱ윜漿뱱윜燇ᰀ
data2 =  s㿣饋⩲齃  ＿걱윜燇ᰀ㿜燇ᱱ윜‿걱윜燇ᱰ㾬燇ᱱ윜︿걱윜燇ᱲ㾬燇ᱱ윜政걱윜燇ᱩ㾬燇ᱱ윜䰿걱윜燇ᱭ㾬燇ᱱ윜漿걱윜燇ᰀ
```

В первом случае у вас строка, где часть символов комп не прочитал выведя ?. Во втором комп вывел нам нормальные иероглифы. 
Чтобы показать что ваш getBytes отработал плохо я записал такую вот вещь:

```
 public class ByteDiff { //Класс для записи двух различных байтов в массив
 byte a;
 byte b;
 int pos;

public ByteDiff(byte a, byte b, int pos) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.pos = pos;
}
  @Override
public String toString() {
    return "pos " + pos + " first byte:" + a + "; second byte: " + b;
}
}

  //Метод сравнения двух массивов байт и записи разности 
  static ArrayList<ByteDiff> disagree(byte [] one, byte [] two){
    System.out.println("Первый длина" +one.length + " второй длина " + two.length);
   ArrayList <ByteDiff> bf = new ArrayList<>();
    if(one.length!=two.length) {
        System.out.println("Массивы не равны.");
    }
    for(int i=0; i<one.length&&i<two.length;i++){
        if(one[i]!=two[i]){
            bf.add(new ByteDiff(one[i], two[i], i));
        }
    }
    return bf;
}


  ArrayList <ByteDiff> bs = disagree(result, workingData);// Вызов метода сравнения двух массивов
   bs.stream().forEach(b-> System.out.println(b)); //распечатка массива сравнения
```

OUTPUT: Массивы не равны. Первый длина 102 второй длина 100

```
pos 10 first byte:-39; second byte: -1
pos 11 first byte:-106; second byte: -3
pos 13 first byte:0; second byte: 18
pos 15 first byte:18; second byte: 0
pos 17 first byte:0; second byte: 9
pos 19 first byte:9; second byte: 63
pos 20 first byte:0; second byte: -32
pos 21 first byte:63; second byte: 0
pos 22 first byte:-32; second byte: 0
pos 27 first byte:0; second byte: 32
pos 28 first byte:0; second byte: 63
pos 29 first byte:32; second byte: -84
pos 30 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 31 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 32 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 33 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 34 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 35 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 36 first byte:-57; second byte: 114
pos 37 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 38 first byte:114; second byte: -84
pos 39 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 40 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 41 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 42 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 43 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 44 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 45 first byte:-57; second byte: 115
pos 46 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 47 first byte:115; second byte: -84
pos 48 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 49 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 50 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 51 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 52 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 53 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 54 first byte:-57; second byte: 100
pos 55 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 56 first byte:100; second byte: -84
pos 57 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 58 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 59 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 60 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 61 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 62 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 63 first byte:-57; second byte: 117
pos 64 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 65 first byte:117; second byte: -84
pos 66 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 67 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 68 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 69 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 70 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 71 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 72 first byte:-57; second byte: 108
pos 73 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 74 first byte:108; second byte: -84
pos 75 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 76 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 77 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 78 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 79 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 80 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 81 first byte:-57; second byte: 109
pos 82 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 83 first byte:109; second byte: -84
pos 84 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 85 first byte:-84; second byte: -57
pos 86 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 87 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 88 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 89 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 90 first byte:-57; second byte: 111
pos 91 first byte:28; second byte: 63
pos 92 first byte:111; second byte: -68
pos 93 first byte:63; second byte: 113
pos 94 first byte:-68; second byte: -57
pos 95 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 96 first byte:-57; second byte: 113
pos 97 first byte:28; second byte: -57
pos 98 first byte:113; second byte: 28
pos 99 first byte:-57; second byte: 0
```

Comment: Ну это выглядит очень странно, мне просто не верится, что кодировка IDE может влиять на работу программы. Я просто щас попытался переключить кодировку, и у меня прога вообще не компилится с ошибкой Error:(1, 1) java: illegal character: '\ufeff'. Это же жесть какая-то.

Comment: Кодировка всему виной. Вам ведь хочется чтобы метод отрабатывал правильно? 
Поставьте в IDE UTF-8 просто методы перепишите как: 
`String data = new String(result, "windows-1251");` 
смените везде UTF-16BE на windows-1251 и будет у вас true true

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, что помогли понять в чём дело, и дали решение, а то я с ума сходил.

Comment: Да не за что. Если ответ был вам полезен, вы можете поставить зелёную галочку слева вверху от ответа. Кроме того вы можете плюсануть ответ этот и другие также слева вверху от ответа.